# Wireshark GUI not runnig on Windows subsystem for Linux

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, wireshark

I have installed Xming on my windows and I have set environment variable `export DISPLAY=:0` on Ubuntu. Other GUI programs, like eog is running. But when I try running Wireshark it shows error messages:

```
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-edvards'
failed to get the current screen resources
Failed to connect to generic netlink.
The X11 connection broke: I/O error (code 1)
XIO:  fatal IO error 2 (No such file or directory) on X server ":0"
      after 366 requests (366 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using VcXsrv and my wireshark GUI launches. Try that and let me know if it works!